# How to make sure my local svn copy is the same as a particular branch revision?

Tags: svn

```
coUp $HADOOP_HOME 1041718 "http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-append"
```

I've written the following bash function to checkout a copy of hadoop if it doesn't exist already, or otherwise make sure it's the same as a checkout. However when the update command is executed against an unmodified checkout it does update (probably against the trunk). Other than removing and checking out the folder each time, what can I do?

```
    function coUp(){
if [[ ! -d $1 ]]
then
    echoThenRun "svn co $3 -r $2 $1"
else
    echoThenRun "svn up $1 -r $2"
fi
checkExit svn
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine, I had some path issues (what's the smiley for embarressment?)